# JQGrid ASP.net C# add edit delete not updating in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, jqgrid

I am using this demo for JQGrid ASP.net C# http://www.trirand.net/examples/grid/editing_data/edit_add_delete/default.aspx

Data is updating and deleting in JQGrid but not in database, how can we update in database also??

Answer (score 0):

In delete function you create a datatable and push data from Database. but you did not exec delete command in database. So it works but not delete from database.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void JQGrid1_RowDeleting(object sender, Trirand.Web.UI.WebControls.JQGridRowDeleteEventArgs e)
        {            
            DataTable dt = GetData();
            dt.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[] { dt.Columns["CustomerID"] };
            DataRow rowToDelete = dt.Rows.Find(e.RowKey);

            if (rowToDelete != null)
{
                dt.Rows.Remove(rowToDelete);
        // store your CustomerID in variable
        string CustomerId = rowToDelete[0].ToString();//Datatype base on your sql table column
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
                sqlConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQL2008_661086_trirandEntities"].ConnectionString;
                sqlConnection.Open();

                string sqlStatement = "delete FROM Customers where CustomerID = "+ CustomerId +"";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement , sqlConnection);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


}

            JQGrid1.DataSource = GetData();
            JQGrid1.DataBind();
}
```

Now your code will work as you want.